# Visual Studio Code SQL Server connection to encrypted database with Azure Key Vault (Always Encrypted)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-code, odbc, azure-keyvault, always-encrypted

I'm trying to get a connection from VSCode on macOS to a SQL Server database that uses *always encrypted* mechanism to protect some of the columns. The master key is stored in an *Azure Key Vault*.

Using the [always encrypted guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2015/10/31/ssms-encryption-wizard-enabling-always-encrypted-in-a-few-easy-steps/) provided by Microsoft is was able to connect successfully to the database.

The same is true for a *simple* connection using VSCode on my mac without turning on the encryption/decryption. I used the *mssql-extension* plugin and providing the necessary information within the settings I was able to query the data

**Settings**

```
"mssql.connections": [
    {
        "server": "XXXXXXXX.database.windows.net",
        "database": "AlwaysEncrypted",
        "authenticationType": "SqlLogin",
        "user": "XXXXX",
        "password": "",
        "emptyPasswordInput": false,
        "savePassword": true,
        "profileName": "AlwaysEncrypted"
    }
]
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM EmployeeDetails
```

**Result**

```
[
  {
    "EmployeeDetailsId": "1",
    "EmployeeNo": "FE00000001",
    "FirstName": "0x013EC8AB61767E1C3D934AB061BCA658B6948637812450C8245DCE4C447F59FD1D6252069A36A67E3477E1C5FB24D860E72FBCC65F98C92B92AB873CE55349672A",
    "MiddleName": "0x015354526EC17EB1151AE918514E565507EDCB5691B4215C45798CA86EB11C47EECA579242926EDFE9F6543006177CBFC03E0F95CD0D8CAE6C941AE173AAF2B925",
    "LastName": "0x0170B3FD2B0416E0607312FB2A67B0F42798EC1871FEAB90AB81235ADACDE1C4F5614099FA3B61E59FEB2D6AD599CB3A9FD031FE56F327F0C80F4BA963EE7E155A",
    "DateOfBirth": "1985-08-12 00:00:00.000"
  }
]
```

Following the two guides

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-always-encrypted-with-the-odbc-driver?view=sql-server-2017
- https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-mssql/wiki/manage-connection-profiles

I did try to create another connection using the *mssql-extension* and providing a **ODBC Connection String** but ultimately failed to get decrypted data when querying (the connection was established just fine). The result was the same as posted above

**Settings with Connection String**

```
"mssql.connections": [
    {
        "server": "XXXXXXXX.database.windows.net",
        "database": "AlwaysEncrypted",
        "authenticationType": "SqlLogin",
        "user": "XXXXX",
        "password": "",
        "emptyPasswordInput": false,
        "savePassword": true,
        "profileName": "AlwaysEncrypted_WithKeyVault",
        "connectionString": "SERVER=XXXXXX.database.windows.net;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=AlwaysEncrypted;ColumnEncryption=Enabled;KeyStoreAuthentication=KeyVaultPassword;KeyStorePrincipalId=USER.NAME@DOMAIN.com;KeyStoreSecret=PASSWORD"
    }
]
```

Can anyone help me to figure out how to setup the connections right, so that the encryption/decryption will he done *transparently* when using VSCode?

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a stale question, but for anyone who also ends up finding this:

I managed to get a successfully connection on VS Code SQL Server by having  the following settings in my settings.json `mssql.connections` array:

```json
   {
      "server": "XXXX.serverhost.domain",
      "database": "XXXX",
      "authenticationType": "SqlLogin",
      "user": "XXXX",
      "password": "",
      "savePassword": true,
      "profileName": "XXXX",

      // specifically the settings below were the important ones
      "encrypt": true,
      "trustServerCertificate": true,
      "persistSecurityInfo": true
    }
```